How to handle concurrent refresh requests ins sveltekit?
In my sveltekit app, I created a 'customFetch' function that will be used in +page.server.js load functions in order to retrieve some data from a third party backend. The catch: The backend uses refresh tokens.
Now, if the customFetch gets a 401 from the backend, it will refresh the tokens and then retry the original fetch. If the refresh fails, meaning the refresh token is expired, the user will be logged out.
The problem: Whenever a user is 'too fast', multiple refreshes are happening concurrently. All refreshes after the first one will use an already expired refresh token. All subsequent refreshes will fail and the user will be logged out.
This seems to be a common problem. Usually the solution is to create a promise. A subsequent refresh must wait for the promise to resolve.
My question concerns sveltekit specifically and where to 'store' the promise. Please bear in mind that the 'customFetch' runs on the server in order to update the httpy only cookies.
If I use universal load functions instead (+page.js), how would I implement the promise? With setContext / getContext?
This is my (pseudo) code:
+page.server.js
import { customFetch } from "$./customFetch.js";

export async function load(event) {
  const fetchSomeData = async () => {
    const res = await customFetch(
      "https://someURL.com",
      {
        method: "GET",
      },
      event
    );

    const data = await res.json();
    return data.data;
  };

  return {
    news: await fetchSomeData(),
  };
}

customFetch.js
export async function customFetch(url, config = {}, event) {
  const { cookies } = event;

  // Make reasonable assumptions if config is not provided
  const headers = config.headers || {};
  const method = config.method || "GET";
  const body = config.body || null;
  let session = cookies.get("session");

  let accessToken = JSON.parse(cookies.get("session"));
  let refreshToken = JSON.parse(cookies.get("session"));

  // Add Authorization header with access token
  if (accessToken) {
    headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
  }

  // Make the initial request
  const response = await event.fetch(url, { method, headers, body });

  if (response.status === 401) {
    // Check if another refresh is already in progress
    if (!refreshPromise) {
      // Start a new refresh process
      refreshPromise = refreshAccessToken(event);
    }

    // Wait for the ongoing refresh process to finish
    await refreshPromise;

    // Retry the original request after the refresh
    return customFetch(url, { method, body, headers }, event);
  }

  // 401 not returned, reset the refresh promise
  refreshPromise = null;

  // refresh token not expired
  return response;
}

async function refreshAccessToken(event) {
  try {
    // Your refresh logic here
    // update cookie with new access token and new refresh token 
    // not possible with http only cookie ?
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle refresh failure
    // logout user
    // delete cookie
  } finally {
    // Reset the refresh promise after completion
    refreshPromise = null;
  }
}


Depending on how/where the application is deployed, this might be impossible since on some platforms the requests are fully independent (possibly even running on different machines due to load balancing).
Assuming you have a single server instance, you could use a dictionary or Map to associate a session cookie with the most recent request promise. This would be single instance in the module responsible for managing the refresh.
If you try to do this via a universal load function, you might run into problems, since the client-side code exists per-tab/window and the code can also run on the server. So the same session (identified via cookie) could quite easily cause concurrent requests if there are multiple tabs, for example.

What about SPA (CSR only), how would you handle it? Use a store in the load functions?

That does not really change anything, would still use a map or dictionary if one session can only have one token. You could still have multiple open tabs/windows and stores are for the client which does not know how many other tags/windows are using the current session.
